# Can I search for issues in ACC via multiple projects?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-construction-cloud

Is there a way in ACC to search for issues of a specified issue type via multiple projects?

Using the following GET request I have to specify the project in the call:
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/issues-issues-GET/

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Issue API itself supports one project data only. you may try with another API: Data Connector API. It can extract issue data of all projects in the job. After the job is done, you could have those data in various csv (issue , issue tye, root causes. By intersecting analyzing the csv, you would be able to get the issue type of all projects.
To get started with Data Connector API, please refer to this blog:
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/bim-360-data-connector-api

Comment: Thx Xiaodong Liang for that hint. But the documentation contains the point "it may take a few minutes before API could return", so we can't use it for an interactive request, where the user is waiting for the response.